# What is the point of the await keyword within an async function in terms of returning a value?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I've researched many many posts and articles, and documentation.  I'm seeking deeper understanding.

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

> The `await` expression causes `async` function execution to pause until a `Promise` is settled, [...]

```js
let fetchLocation = () => {
  //fetches information from satellite system and 
  //returns a Vector2 of lat long on earth
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve({
        lat: 73,
        long: -24
      });
    }, 2000);
  });
}

//async functions automatically return a promise.
let main = async() => {

  //awaits the promises resolution
  let result = await fetchLocation();
  console.log("I'm the awaited promise result", result)

  //immediately returns a promise as promise pending 
  return result;
}

console.log(main().then(res => console.log("I'm the original promise, just passed along by the async function, it didn 't a-wait for me", res)))
```

Before going down this rabbit hole, I knew async/await was syntactical sugar to make async code look synchronous.

I therefore fully expected to see main return the lat long coordinates. Instead it returns a promise.

A couple questions.

1. Is the MDN documentation wrong? Does it not actually pause execution? It seems that the await keyword does not actually "pause" function execution... invoking main immediately returns a `Promise<pending>` object. However, after it returns we receive the value of the fulfilled promise in the awaited variable `result`.  I suppose this came from the event loop? (And an async return statement is still synchronous.)
2. So it seems that await unwraps a promise, and async wraps a promise, but you need to use await within async.  I get that await might actually be promise.then() underneath the hood but if they want to make it fully synchronous in appearance, why not have the async function return the resolved promise value when used with await?  Otherwise async await seems a bit redundant.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're proposing exactly. You're wondering why `async`/`await` doesn't behave exactly like sync code without using those keywords? If nothing else, that would prevent the caller from _not_ using `await` immediately, which is a pretty common use case. `await` pauses the execution as you can see from the 2 second delay before "I'm the awaited promise result" logs, but the synchronous call stack code still runs and returns the promise. [Good video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ) that might help explain why you see the sync code run first.

Comment: _"I therefore fully expected to see main return the lat long coordinates. Instead it returns a promise."_: `async` functions _always_ return a promise.

Comment: I'm more so wondering how this async main function can be two things apparently simultaneously.  It can be synchronous in the case of the return statement which would imply that it did not wait.  And also somehow wait asynchronously.  I'm thinking in terms of an interpreter reading the function line by line.  Also what I'm proposing is more like isn't await just chaining a then underneath the hood to the returned promise object, so what makes it better?

Answer (score 5):

> Is the MDN documentation wrong?

No

> Does it not actually pause execution?

It pauses the execution of the `async` function, hands a Promise back to the calling function — because it hasn't reached the point in the `async` function where it knows what to return — then the execution of the calling function (and the rest of the code) continues.

> However, after it returns we receive the value of the fulfilled promise in the awaited variable result. I suppose this came from the event loop?

When the event loop stops being busy (running the code that called the `async` function in the first place and anything else that it picks up in the meantime) *and* the promise that was being `await`ed resolves, then the `async` function is woken up and given the resolved value of the function to continue processing.

> why not have the async function return the resolved promise value when used with await?

Because that would block the entire event loop, which is why asynchronous logic (starting with callback style APIs) was introduced into JS in the first place.

> Otherwise async await seems a bit redundant.

Consider a situation where you want to request a number of URLs from an API serially (so that you don't shove too many simultaneous requests at the API):

```
const data = [];
for (let i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
    const response = await fetch(urls[i]);
    const response_data = await response.json();
    data.push(response_data);
}
```

If you were to rewrite that without `await` then you'd probably end up with something recursive to count your way through the loop. It would be significantly more complex.

`async`/`await` makes dealing with complex combinations of promises simple, and simple promises trivial.

> knew async/await was syntactical sugar to make async code look synchronous.

And it does that *inside the `async` function* and **only** inside it.

Comment: The makes a lot more sense viewing it in context with the outer synchronous execution environment.  My next question is since main is an async function, but it immediately returns to continue the main the thread, how does it wake back up later? Wouldn't it be tossed off the call stack as soon as it returns?

Comment: @user14716012 — No, because that is what `async` does.

Comment: Yes, but how? Usually when a function returns something it is popped off the call stack and slated for garbage collection, unless I guess it contains a closure.  I'm curious how this works with an async function.

Comment: Also couldn't the example above also be written as 
```
const data = [];
for (let i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
    fetch(urls[i])
    .then(res => {
       res.json()
       .then(res => data.push(result)
    }
}
```
I suppose it is a bit more succinct with await syntax though.

Comment: "Yes, but how?" — That's an implementation detail dependant on the specific JS engine.

Comment: "Also couldn't the example above also be written as" — No, since (a) that runs them in parallel and I was specific about wanting them serially and (b) after the `for` loop finishes the `data` array hasn't been populated because none of the promises will have resolved (you'd need additional logic to trigger the next step which would have to figure out when the last promise had resolved)

Comment: Very interesting. Thanks for the knowledge!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241464/discussion-between-user14716012-and-quentin).

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really pause the function, it just allows you to write the rest of the function code as if it were. But it's really just wrapping the rest of the code of the function into a `.then()`.

E.g.

```
await foo = someFunc();
console.log(foo);
```

is executed like

```
someFunc().then((foo => {
    console.log(foo);
});
```

Since it's really still asynchronous, you can't return the resolved value, because the original calling function returns immediately. But if the calling function is also declared `async`, it returns a `Promise`, and the caller can either use `await` again (so it appears to be synchronous) or use `.then()`.

Comment: Interesting that it's just syntactical sugar for chaining .then

Comment: Found something new, all lines of code above the await in the main async function are run synchronously, all lines below the await (besides the return statement) are run async and sent to the event loop

Comment: That's essentially what `.then()` does.

Comment: "The fundamental difference between await and promises is that await suspends execution of the current function, while promise. then() continues execution of the current function after adding the X call to the callback chain."

Comment: That's simplifying the situation, by describing how it appears to work from the programmer's perspective, not how it's actually implemented under the covers.

Comment: Also I'm curious how it is implemented underneath if you have the time.

Comment: But that's what `await` does. It packages the rest of the function into a callback.

Comment: The real benefit is when you have a series of `await` statements. You can write them sequentially instead of using heavily nested callbacks.

Comment: I don't really know exactly what's going on in the implementation, I've seen references to microtasks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241442/discussion-between-user14716012-and-barmar).